# How do I create multiple tables with the display:table tag?

Tags: java, jsp, displaytag

I have created a table showing medical claims as follows:

```
<display:table id="claimItem" class="table table-bordered table-striped"
           name="claimItems" pagesize="10"
           requestURI="/individual/health/spg-items.do?section=GENMD" export="false" sort="list"
           defaultorder="ascending" defaultsort="1"
           excludedParams="paging">

<display:column title="Service Date" sortable="true">
    ${claimItem.date}
</display:column>
<display:column title="Patient" sortable="true">
    ${claimItem.patient}
</display:column>
<display:column title="Healthcare Professional" sortable="true">
    ${claimItem.provider}
</display:column>
</display:table>
```

However, I need to create a separate table for each section of medicine, not just "GENMD", and I'd like to do so with a loop, passing in the section as a variable, which changes the id of the table. But since the id of the table is used as the variable representing the current item, this is causing some issues. If I insert the variable into the table name, id and requestURI, I don't know how to reference the current claim item:

```
<display:table id="${section}item" class="table table-bordered table-striped"
       name="${section}items" pagesize="10"
       requestURI="/individual/health/spg-items.do?section=${section}" export="false" sort="list"
       defaultorder="ascending" defaultsort="1"
       excludedParams="paging">

<display:column title="Service Date" sortable="true">
    ${sectionitem.date} <!-- How do I access this claim item? -->
</display:column>
<display:column title="Patient" sortable="true">
    ${sectionitem.patient} <!-- How do I access this claim item? -->
</display:column>
<display:column title="Healthcare Professional" sortable="true">
    ${sectionitem.provider} <!-- How do I access this claim item? -->
</display:column>
</display:table>
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is `${section}` in URI? Where is `section` variable set?

Comment: ${section} is a request parameter passed through to the page. It can take on one of a number of values: CMEDS, GENMD, CMSA etc. which determines which claims are returned from the server.

Comment: Have you tried `${pageScope[section + 'items'].date}`?